# Moving my LAMP to Amazon

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront

I have a small LAMP application that I want to move to Amazon

- I will need Amazon EC2 for this, right?
- I want my static resources delivered from a CDN. Does that mean I need Amazon's CloudFront along with EC2? (Or is EC2 also a CDN somehow?)
- I would also like to use a PHP accelerator (probably APC), memcache, etc. Will I be able to do this on Amazon?
- Will I still be able to use MySQL? (I ask this because it seems that Amazon also has their own RDBMS; not sure if I am forced to use theirs)

Comment: The answer looks like you are afraid to change to a new server, if you have a root access, then you are able to do whatever you wish in your server.. mysql, php, gcc, whatever..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I will need Amazon EC2 for this, right?

Yes.

> I want my static resources delivered from a CDN. Does that mean I need Amazon's CloudFront along with EC2? (Or is EC2 also a CDN somehow?)

CloudFront is a CDN, but you can use any other CDN just like you would with a site hosted on your own servers. EC2 is not a CDN.

> I would also like to use a PHP accelerator (probably APC), memcache, etc. Will I be able to do this on Amazon?

Yes, you have full root access to the server. You can install any software you'd install on a server you owned yourself.

> Will I still be able to use MySQL? (I ask this because it seems that Amazon also has their own RDBMS; not sure if I am forced to use theirs)

Yes. RDS is neat, but you can always run MySQL on your EC2 server.

Answer (score -2):

I think so!

Take a look at this paper -> http://aws.amazon.com/solutions/global-solution-providers/mysql/

The best to do is open a ticket with them or call it to clear all your doubts. A call is always the best way, you can ask about all your specific needs, then ask for a contract, if it is in a contract you are in a safe side.

Comment: which question did you answer? Just the MySQL one? And does Amazon offer individualized contracts???